# Does this relation imply that a given collection is open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis for $X$.

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following two conditions:

> 1. For each $B\in \mathscr{B}$, there exists $A\in \mathscr{A}$ such that $A\subset B$.
> 2. For each $A\in \mathscr{A}$, there exists $B\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $B\subset A$.

In this case, are the elements of $\mathscr{A}$ open?

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}$ are the non-empty open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ the closed intervals, then (1) and (2) are satisfied, but the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are not open.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Oh, right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general, in a $T_3$ space, we could take $\mathcal{A}$ to be the set of closed sets with non-empty interior or the family of regular closed sets, and these need not be open sets (e.g. in a connected space most of them cannot be). MoonLightSyzygy's comment is a special case.

As an aside, any collection of sets $\mathcal{A}$ such that for any open set $O$ of $X$ and any $x \in O$ we have $A \in \mathcal{A}$ with $x \in A \subseteq O$ (so a controlled version of 1. in a way) is called a *network* for the topology (if its members are open it would be a base), and such families are sometimes considered as a useful generalisation of a base.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Let $\mathscr B=\{(b,b'):b,b'\in \Bbb R; b<b'\}$ and $\mathscr A=\{(a,a']:a,a'\in \Bbb R; a<a'\}.$ No member of $\mathscr A$ is open.

For 1., if $b<b'$  then $(b,b')\supset (b, (b+b')/2]\in \mathscr A.$

For 2., if $a<a'$ then $(a,a']\supset (a,a')\in \mathscr B.$